# Can't update object in database

Tags: javascript, angularjs, mongodb, express

I'm trying to update an array in one of my database objects.

I'm checking the object before making a `put` request. But the object won't update in my MongoDB database.

**client/entry/newEntry.controller.js**:

```
$scope.save = function(form) {
    $scope.submitted = true;
    $scope.entry.date = Date.now;
    $scope.entry.writer = $scope.getCurrentUser;
    $scope.entry.type = 'chapter';
    getHighestArticleId();
    $scope.entry.articleId = articleId;

    if(form.$valid) {
      $http.post('/api/entrys', $scope.entry)
        .success(function(data){
          console.log(' -- posted entry --');
          console.log('data: ', data);
          $scope.entry = data;

          console.log($scope.entry.orphan);
          if($scope.entry.orphan == false){
              $scope.parent.children.push($scope.entry);

              console.log(' -- parent to update --');
              console.log($scope.parent);

              $http.put('/api/entrys/' + $scope.parent._id)
                .success(function(data){
                  console.log(' -- updated parent --');
                  console.log(data);
                });
          }
        });
    }
};
```

entry **api/entry/index.js**:

```
'use strict';

var express = require('express');
var controller = require('./entry.controller');

var router = express.Router();

router.get('/', controller.index);
router.get('/:id', controller.show);
router.get('/:id/children/', controller.getChildren);
router.get('/type/:type', controller.getByType);
router.get('/type/:type/orphan/:hasParent', controller.getByTypeAndOrphan);
router.post('/', controller.create);
router.put('/:id', controller.update);
router.patch('/:id', controller.update);
router.delete('/:id', controller.destroy);

module.exports = router;
```

**api/entry/entry.controller.js**:

```
// Updates an existing entry in the DB.
exports.update = function(req, res) {
  if(req.body._id) { 
      delete req.body._id; 
  }
  Entry.findById(req.params.id, function (err, entry) {
    if (err) { 
        return handleError(res, err); 
    }

    if(!entry) { 
        return res.send(404); 
    }

    var updated = _.merge(entry, req.body);

    updated.save(function (err) {
      if (err) { 
          return handleError(res, err); 
      }
      return res.json(200, entry);
    });
  });
};
```

---

***EDIT***

**routes.js**:

```
/**
 * Main application routes
 */

'use strict';

var errors = require('./components/errors');

module.exports = function(app) {

  // Insert routes below
  app.use('/api/languages', require('./api/language'));
  app.use('/api/forums', require('./api/forum'));
  app.use('/api/entrys', require('./api/entry'));
  app.use('/api/things', require('./api/thing'));
  app.use('/api/users', require('./api/user'));

  app.use('/auth', require('./auth'));

  // All undefined asset or api routes should return a 404
  app.route('/:url(api|auth|components|app|bower_components|assets)/*')
   .get(errors[404]);

  // All other routes should redirect to the index.html
  app.route('/*')
    .get(function(req, res) {
      res.sendfile(app.get('appPath') + '/index.html');
    });
};
```

Comment: In you index.js do you have any routes defined for `'/api/entrys'`? I can only see post and put for `'/:id'`

Comment: Are you getting any error while doing this ?

Comment: @chridam: Just added some more information, is this what you are looking for.

Comment: @Mutant: No I don't get any errors

Comment: And how are you updating data in `require('./api/entry')`?

Comment: @chridam: that one is calling my `index.js`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found the answer. The problem was in three places. The first in my call to the api

```
$http.put('/api/entrys/' + $scope.parent._id)
   .success(function(data){
      console.log(' -- updated parent --');
      console.log(data);
});
```

should instead be

```
$http.put('/api/entrys/' + $scope.parent._id, $scope.parent)
   .success(function(data){
      console.log(' -- updated parent --');
      console.log(data);
});
```

The second problem was my child object. I passed the entire object, but only needed the id, so my push should change from this

```
$scope.parent.children.push($scope.entry);
```

to this

```
$scope.parent.children.push($scope.entry._id);
```

Finally my update function itself needed to be informed that I was handling the sub-document. Which meant that I had to add this to the function

```
// Updates an existing entry in the DB.
exports.update = function(req, res) {
  if(req.body._id) { 
      delete req.body._id; 
  }
  Entry.findById(req.params.id, function (err, entry) {
    if (err) { 
        return handleError(res, err); 
    }

    if(!entry) { 
        return res.send(404); 
    }

    var updated = _.merge(entry, req.body);

    entry.markModified('children');

    updated.save(function (err) {
      if (err) { 
          return handleError(res, err); 
      }
      return res.json(200, entry);
    });
  });
};
```